# Why is it that Silverlight 5 not work consistently well on Mac OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, silverlight

I have customers who are showing me Mac OS X core dumps that show calls being made to the Mac OS X that cause a Signal Abort (SIGABRT), upon opening the default Silverlight preferences on the Mac.  Also, our Silverlight 5 app does not start up on that machine.

By Silverlight 5, I mean 5.1.10411.0.

The customers who seem to be having the most trouble are using Mac OS X 10.8.2 (the latest Mountain Lion)

I have a Mac that runs Silverlight 5 perfectly but it is a Mac OS X 10.6.8 machine (Snow Leopard). Our app also runs as expected on that Mac machine.

There is a lot of evidence on the Internet that many people have been having this same kind of problem.  There are lots of supposedly "miraculous" solutions, but it doesn't seem to be right that end users would have to jump through hoops to get this to work.  People having problems with Netflix on Macs, and problems where a program called MacKeeper messes up the Silverlight installation.  I just want to know what gives rise to issues like this?  Is it that Microsoft is not consistently testing Silverlight well whenever Mac comes out with a new version of the Mac OS X, or would it be more likely that Apple is specifically trying to subvert Microsoft Silverlight (and other programs apparently) on purpose for some reason? There are apparently a lot of random crashes happening on Mac OS X 10.8.2, with Microsoft Office, and other non-Microsoft applications.  Anyone have any insight into the reasons behind this?  Does Silverlight work fine for you on your Mac OS X 10.8.2 machine?

Who is at fault on this? Apple or Microsoft? Both? Neither?

Microsoft has stated that they plan to support Silverlight through 2021.
Is there a subtext that it is really only supported on Windows though?
The entire point of having made an application in Silverlight in the first place, for many decision makers, would have been so that it will be able to be run on a Mac.  Why can't Apple and Microsoft play nicely, at least in a particular instance where interoperability was showcased and marketed as something that could be relied upon to just work.  (Why can't we all just get along? Stop. That was rhetorical.)

Did Microsoft test Silverlight on an older version of Mac OS X only to have Apple change something in the next revision of Mac OS X?

Are my customers and other people on the Internet doing something unsupportable like run 3rd party utilities that are corrupting the Silverlight installation process?

Is this going to end up being just some sort of permissions issue?

Is Mac OS X 10.8.2 simply buggy or generally unstable?  Are there other apps that just crash on Mountain Lion?  What has to be done to avoid that - has Apple deprecated some API calls?

Theories, speculations, insider insights and other types of input are welcomed!

Please just do not resort to passionate bashing of corporate entities, as that is pointless.  I just want to know how this can be smoothed out, and who to call to make things happen.  I don't want to know who is "evil" - I just want to know who is not doing their job correctly.

Here is the thread that crashes upon Silverlight just trying to show its Preferences:

```
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9114da6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99467acf pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9949e4f8 abort + 168
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a00b8d4 0xa000000 + 47316
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a00b958 0xa000000 + 47448
5   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a00b3e8 0xa000000 + 46056
6   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a103b27 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 193895
7   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a037553 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
8   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a10130c GetCLRRuntimeHost + 183628
9   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a101445 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 183941
10  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a1069a6 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 205798
11  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a106b5b GetCLRRuntimeHost + 206235
12  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a1c94be GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1003262
13  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a1ca005 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1006149
14  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a27a5ea GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1728554
15  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0a339c94 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2512596
16  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x000050ac start + 5624
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9279e586 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90f1bb64 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 228
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x97263011 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1180
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x97241572 loadNib + 373
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x9724094a +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 233
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x973919a4 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 154
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x9724061f +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 709
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x9723c498 NSApplicationMain + 447
25  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x00003baf start + 251
26  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x00003add start + 41
```

Comment: Update - new information from my customers - it seems that this could be due to some corruption of Mac OS X, and not something that will necessarily occur in a default state.